# What does the phrase 'odiously precocious' mean in the following passage?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, ambiguity

'He thought of the half-caste children in Apia. They had an unhealthy look, sallow and pale, and they were ***odiously precocious***'

In my point of view it simply means that the children have so many talents that they seem odious, but that doesn't make any sense and is kind of funny too.

Thank you .

Comment: Sounds like possibly an example of poor writing.

Comment: It’s from a story, The Pool
          by William Somerset Maugham

Answer (score 2):

*Precocious* doesn't mean *multi-talented*. It means [*having developed certain abilities or inclinations at an earlier age than is usual or expected*.](https://www.lexico.com/definition/precocious) It is often used disparagingly, perhaps because precocious children are often show-offs.

As *Odiously* means [repulsively](https://www.lexico.com/definition/odious), "odiously precocious" is extremely critical. It's a surprisingly harsh way to describe children.

It seems there may be a slight divergence in US/UK usage.

[Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/precocious) says this:

> precocious /adjective
> a precocious child shows intelligence or skill at a very young age, or behaves in an adult way –
> *sometimes used to show disapproval in British English*

and [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/precocious) says:

---

**(especially of children) showing mental development or achievement much earlier than usual:**

- *A precocious child, she went to university at the age of 15.*

---

disapproving
**A precocious child behaves as if they are much older than they are:**

- *a precocious little brat*

The ambivalence is shown clearly at [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/precocious) where, of the 24 synonyms given, more than half (marked with an asterisk) are disapproving:

bright,
*cocky,  intelligent,  mature,  advanced,
*aggressive,  ahead of time,  beforehand,  ?bold,
*brassy,
*cheeky,  developed,  early,
*flip,
*flippant,
*forward,
*fresh,
*nervy,  premature,
*presumptuous,
*pushy,  quick,
*sassy,
*smart-alecky

In the UK, it seems to me, 'precocious' is so often followed by 'brat' that even 'precocious *child'* has become disapproving. But speaking, for example, of someone's precocious *talent*, or describing someone as a precocious *pianist* expresses no such disapproval.

Comment: I have met some distinctly odiously precocious children. Usually it is the fault of pushy parents.

Comment: @Michael Harvey So have I, and described them in a similar fashion. The passage as a whole seemed to lack humour though. 'Half-caste' is pretty offensive these days. But perhaps it's from an earlier time. Robert Louis Stevenson perhaps, being about Samoa.

Comment: When I was very little, a family story goes, my mother took me to a health clinic to be weighed. The district nurse picked me up and said "What does your mummy call you?". I allegedly replied "Precocious". I hope I was not odiously so. My first words were "I like turkey", apparently delivered at a Christmas meal at what must have been the age of 20 months. This, I can confidently say, is entirely characteristic (I still love food).

Comment: @Old Brixtonian it is not always used disparagingly, as the definition in the Oxford dictionary goes it means 
'(of a child) having developed certain abilities or proclivities at an earlier age than usual' ,it is simply someone who is ahead of their time.

Comment: Perhaps Maugham calls them 'odiously precocious' because they already  look pale and sallow like the adult natives of Samoa,and not innocent and soft like other white children.

Comment: You're right: it isn't always disparaging. Following 'odiously' it is.

Comment: @Mumbas11 The word 'forward' used to be used as a criticism of children who were too self-confident, too uninhibited and asked a lot of impertinent or personal questions. It covered children who were "heard as well as seen" as opposed to those who complied with the Victorian ideal that "children should be seen and not heard". Since 'forward' was being used in this way up to the 1950s at least, I suspect that  Maugham was describing a class of children he considered 'forward' to an objectionable degree.

Comment: @Boldben - the word 'pert' used to be used like 'forward' in that way.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian— What is a positive counterpart of _precocious_? I always thought it was used in a positive way.

Comment: @user405662 I should have amended my answer (ages ago!) to say that 'precocious' isn't always disapproving. I've now done so, and I hope I've made it clear that the sense of disapproval is confined to the UK and that, even here, speaking of someone's (even a child's) precocious ability, or to say eg, "he was a precocious writer" is nothing but positive.

Comment: @Mumbas11: This question was asked a long time ago, but someone just brought it to life! I should have thanked you for your just criticism and corrected my answer at the time, but I got distracted. I've done both now, I hope.

Comment: Thank you, @Old Brixtonian!

Comment: @Michael Harvey: :-) Good story. ('What does your Mummy call you.') Sorry the grin is so late: I can't have seen it.